# View only the new entries in a growing log file

Tags: logs, tail

```
tail -f x.log
```

I use this command to see a growing log file in the command prompt.

I am interested only in seeing the log lines that are written to the file after running `tail -f` and not interested in the logs that were written to the file before doing `tail -f`. But `tail -f` command on start, takes the last 10 lines and displays it.

This confuses me, at times if these logs are freshly generated (or) they are old logs?

So, how can i customize tail -f to output only the new entries?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can try:

```
tail -n0 -f x.log
```

From [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tail):

> **-n, --lines=**K
>       output the last K lines, instead of the last 10; or use -n +K to output lines starting with the Kth

Answer (score 13):

You can use the `-n0` option to show 0 lines. So

```
tail -n0 -f some.log
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `less` command like

1. `less file_name.log` (log file will be opened and will show first page of the log file)
2. press <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> (to act same as like tail -f)
3. In case if you need to search for any keyword in log file. press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> to exit the tail mode and search for the keyword as <kbd>/</kbd>keyword and <kbd>?</kbd>keyword.

Comment: This does not view **only the new entries** in a growing log file.

Answer (score 0):

I've created this approach when I had to monitor entries inside docker container:

```bsh
LOG_COUNT=0
LOGS=/var/logs/your_logs

function HEART_BEAT() {
    LOG_COUNT_NEW=$(wc -l $LOGS | awk '{ print $1 }')
    tail -n $(( $LOG_COUNT_NEW - $LOG_COUNT )) $LOGS
    LOG_COUNT=$LOG_COUNT_NEW
}
```

Hope this helps!